# itertools.islice implementation -- efficiently slicing a list

Tags: python, slice, python-itertools

Earlier, I was trying to answer a question where I wanted to iterate over a list slice as efficiently as possible.

```
for x in lst[idx1:]:
```

isn't ideal as it creates a copy (In general, this is `O(n)`).  My next thought was to use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).  But if you look at the documentation, it appears that `islice` will call `next` until it finds the index it is looking for at which point it will start to yield values.  This is also `O(n)`.  It seems that there is an optimization that is available here if the object passed to `islice` is a `list` or a `tuple` -- It seems that you could iterate over the "slice" directly (in C) without actually making a copy.  I was curious if this optimization is in [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/efedd0f62a7e/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l1370), But I didn't find anything.  I'm not extremely familiar with C and the python source tree, so it's entirely possible that I missed it.

My question is this:

> Is there a way to iterate over a list "slice" without making a copy of the list slice and without burning through a bunch of unwanted elements (in an optimized C implementation)?

I'm well aware that I could write my own generator for this (very naively, not accounting for the fact that many of the arguments should be optional, etc.):

```
def myslice(obj,start,stop,stride):
    for i in xrange(start,stop,stride):
        yield obj[i]
```

but that's definitely not going to beat an optimized C implementation.

---

If you're wondering why I would need this over just looping over a slice directly, consider the difference between:

```
takewhile(lambda x: x == 5, lst[idx:])  #copy's the tail of the list unnecessarily
```

and

```
takewhile(lambda x: x == 5, islice(lst,idx,None)) #inspects the head of the list unnecessarily
```

and finally:

```
takewhile(lambda x: x == 5, magic_slice(lst,idx,None)) #How to create magic_slice???
```

Comment: The iteration itself is O(n). iteration plus slice is still O(n). iterations plus islice is also O(n). Just do the cleanest thing now and worry about the speed when it becomes an issue and worry about the big-O stuff later or never.

Comment: @Duncan -- But the iteration doesn't have to be order N.  Suppose I only want the first M elements from the slice?  (M isn't necessarily static -- It could be based on some "predicate" function).  I also agree that premature optimization can make code harder to read.  I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: Mind you -- svn.python.org is not updated anymore. The source code is now at hg.python.org/cpython. (I've mailed the python.org webmaster that he might put a notice atop svn.python explaining this, to no effect.)

Comment: @larsmans -- Thanks for fixing that for me.  I just googled `itertools source code` and that was the first thing that came up.  Maybe we should get Guido to fix that.  He works at google doesn't he? ;-)

Comment: Hi Actually I was trying to understand a code which was somewhat related to this post and was curious to know you mentioned **"But if you look at the documentation, it appears that islice will call next until it finds the index it is looking for at which point it will start to yield values. This is also O(n)."** Is this correct?If it's possible can you quote the source too? thanks. For ref as per my the time complexity of the code mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77730584/19090048) answer is `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to iterate over a list "slice" without making a copy of the list slice and without burning through a bunch of unwanted elements (in an optimized C implementation)?

Yes there is, if you write that C implementation. [Cython](http://cython.org/) makes this particularly easy.

```
cdef class ListSlice(object):
    cdef object seq
    cdef Py_ssize_t start, end

    def __init__(self, seq, Py_ssize_t start, Py_ssize_t end):
        self.seq = seq
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.start == self.end:
            raise StopIteration()
        r = self.seq[self.start]
        self.start += 1
        return r
```

Comment: *grumbles* -- I keep thinking that someday I'll teach myself Cython (even read the tutorial once or twice), but I keep putting off really using it because my fortran skills are better than my C skills and `f2py` just makes my life so easy.  I suppose this is a case where `f2py` is simply inadequate and maybe I should bite the bullet and brush up on my C/Cython.

Comment: @mgilson I know it has been a long time since you posted this but how does this work?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's worth mentioning that NumPy slices are non-copying (they create a view onto the underlying array). Therefore, if you can use NumPy arrays for your data, that would solve the problem. On top of that you could get additional performance improvements through vectorization.

Comment: "if you can use Numpy arrays for your data" is a pretty big constraint here -- You can't `.append` efficiently to a numpy array.  However, this is still a very good point.  (+1).

Comment: @mgilson: It is a big constraint indeed. NumPy doesn't lends itself to every problem, but when it does work, it works really well.

Comment: How does that improve on `itertools.islice`, which is also non-copying?

Comment: @larsmans Wow - it seems you and the OP are right. `islice` really *does* start at the first object and call `obj->tp_iternext()` until it gets to the correct index. I'm kind of shocked that it doesn't do something like `if isinstance(obj, list): start = obj[index]; current = index` to do an O(1) skip into the middle of the object.

Comment: @KirkStrauser: so am I, but then all of `itertools` is really meant to support a kind of lazy processing style on streaming data. You're free to submit a patch, of course :)

Comment: @larsmans I've been known to [play around in that problem space](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IterDict), but I'll leave the C hacking to people who don't mind that layer of insanity. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use PyPy (which you might, since you care about performance), they optimize string slicing to be non-copying: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/interpreter-optimizations.html

Comment: I've often wondered if any implementations took advantage of a strings immutability in that way.  Anyway, this still doesn't work for arbitrary sequences.

Answer (score 0):

`islice` is a function from `itertools` module, so it works (and definitely should work) with `iterator`s in general, not only with `list`s. So, you can't find your optimization in `itertools` source code, cause it should work with any given iterator.

Right approach in your case is:

```
def magic_slice(lst, start, end=None):
    for pos in xrange(start, (end or len(lst))):
        yield lst[pos]
```

`takewhile` will call your generator "one-by-one", and it will `yield` new values - the same "speed" as for generic list walking + `xrange` iterating. So the overhead in such implementation is minimal. If you need more - you can rewrite such function on C level but I don't see many advantages to do this.

Comment: The fact that it should work with any iterator/iterable does not bar special implementations for sequences.

Comment: While I agree that itertools should continue to work for any iterable, there are examples in the source code where things are special cased for `lists` and `tuples` since you can do it more efficiently when you're using those datatypes.  (see the code for `list.extend` for example)