# How to increment each sublist in a given list by a step of one?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose that there is a list with n elements, i.e. x = [23,25,3,45,67,89,67,45,4,6,...n]. What data structure and/or program would be most suitable for converting x to a list of sublists, with each sublist incrementing by a length of one, i.e. y = [[23],[25,3],[45,67,89],[67,45,4,6]].

In other words, suppose an array A of length L of elements n. Given i intervals for each subset or subarray of array/list A[i] which data structure would be most suitable for partitioning the array to subarrays each incrementing their elements by one for each iteration i.e. A[i] = [A[n+1],A[(n+1)+1],A[((n+1)+1)+1], ...]. Assuming the first subarray A[n+1] only has one element.

Comment: What would happen if say `x = [23,25,3,45,67,89,67,45,4,6,12]`(11 elements). Is this kind of input allowed and if allowed what would be the expected output?

Comment: @mandy8055 No. Assume the total number of elements in the array/list is s.t. that doesn't happen.

Comment: Just store the start and end points for any further computation if you ask me. Don't store the entire element set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple programming approach, Python, without the need for any complex data structures besides a list.

```
def create_increasing_sublists(array):
    sublists = []
    start = 0
    length = 1

    while start + length <= len(array):
        sublists.append(array[start:start + length])
        start += length
        length += 1

    return sublists

# Example usage
x = [23, 25, 3, 45, 67, 89, 67, 45, 4, 6]  # Your list can be of any length
y = create_increasing_sublists(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: How about `while start < len(array)`? And you got the precedences wrong, `array[start:start + length]` should rather be `array[start : start+length]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iterator from `x`, and use `itertools.islice` to get an incrementally bigger slice from the iterator:

```
from itertools import islice

x = [23, 25, 3, 45, 67, 89, 67, 45, 4, 6]
y = []
seq = iter(x)
while sublist := list(islice(seq, 0, len(y) + 1)):
    y.append(sublist)
print(y)
```

This outputs:

```
[[23], [25, 3], [45, 67, 89], [67, 45, 4, 6]]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/n17bMh

Comment: This has quadratic time complexity: `O(len^2)`. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It does not. Please understand what an iterator does. It iterates over the sequence once and only once.

Comment: thanks. Actually I do not have much hands on python knowledge and am still learning but was thinking won't `islice(seq, 0, len(y) + 1)` call takes `O(len(y) + 1)` time in the worst case as well? And `list(islice(...))` call takes `O(len(y) + 1)` time in the worst case because it converts the iterator slice to a list. But thanks for confirming. I will read up on it.

Comment: You may be confused by my use of `len(y) + 1` as a shortcut to using a separate counter variable. `len(y) + 1` takes advantage of the fact that the length of the output list `y` grows incrementally with each `append`. The sum of all the `len(y) + 1`s in the end will equal `len(x)`, so slicing `len(y) + 1` from the iterator in each iteration will add up to the length of the input in the end, resulting in a *O(n)* time complexity.

Comment: sorry for bothering you again: please take a look at these posts, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738746/19090048 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628934/itertools-islice-implementation-efficiently-slicing-a-list#comment137036605_13628934

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily efficient due to reconstruction of the input list but concise:

```
x = [23,25,3,45,67,89,67,45,4,6]

i = 0
result = []

while x := x[i:]:
    i += 1
    result.append(x[:i])

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[23], [25, 3], [45, 67, 89], [67, 45, 4, 6]]
```

**EDIT:**

Just for fun, I have consolidated three functionally equivalent approaches to this question from this and other answers.

```
from itertools import islice
from timeit import timeit

x = [23, 25, 3, 45, 67, 89, 67, 45, 4, 6]


# very concise but worst performer
def func1(x):
    it = iter(x)
    return [[z, *islice(it, i)] for i, z in enumerate(it)]


# concise and outperforms func1
def func2(x):
    i = 0
    result = []
    while x := x[i:]:
        i += 1
        result.append(x[:i])
    return result


# least concise but best performance
def func3(x):
    result = []
    index = i = 0
    lx = len(x)
    while index < lx:
        i += 1
        result.append(x[index : index + i])
        index += i
    return result

assert func1(x) == func2(x)
assert func1(x) == func3(x)

for func in func1, func2, func3:
    print(func.__name__, timeit(lambda: func(x)))
```

**Output:**

```
func1 1.1316846249974333
func2 0.7870362920002663
func3 0.5471352499953355
```

Which, if nothing else, proves that less code isn't always most efficient

**Platform:**

```
Python 3.12.1
Apple M2
```

Comment: For `x = [0] * 5050`, func1 is already ~10 times faster than func2 for me.

Comment: @KellyBundy You are quite right that func1 outperforms func2 as the list gets longer. However, func3 continues to outperform both func1 and func2 when the length of x is significantly longer than OP's sample (tested at 10,000 elements)

Comment: Yeah, func3 is faster. func1 wasn't trying to be fastest, it's just reasonably fast and works if the input is an arbitrary iterable (and hopefully it's interesting/educational, that's also why I upvoted yours).

Comment: I *think* func2 takes Theta(n^1.5) time, but just based on guessing/experimenting. Doesn't look trivial to prove. Might be a decent question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list `y` that contains sublists from `x` with creates non-overlapping sublists in y with incrementing lengths in *`O(n)`* time. Something like:

```py
x = [23, 25, 3, 45, 67, 89, 67, 45, 4, 6]
y = []
index = 0

for i in range(1, len(x) + 1):
    if index + i > len(x):
        break
    sublist = x[index:index + i]
    y.append(sublist)
    index += i

print(y)
```

***[SAMPLE RUN](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zxtqbsfq)***

Comment: Where is the list comprehension that you allude to?

Comment: @CtrlZ thanks for calling out . I did the correction. I was initially inclined to provide a solution based on OP's requirement where there can be overlapping element in the sublists. But after the clarification I found it was no longer needed but was not able to edit the solution

Answer (score 0):

Another iterator/islice solution. Take one value and 0 more, then one value and 1 more, then one value and 2 more, etc. Reasonably fast and works for any input iterable, not just lists.

```py
from itertools import islice

x = [23, 25, 3, 45, 67, 89, 67, 45, 4, 6]

it = iter(x)
y = [[z, *islice(it, i)]
     for i, z in enumerate(it)]

print(y)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BDoIwEEX3c4q_BFM3iIoLTkJYGFPiJLQlZUiAk5i4YaN38ja2qc7mzc_8-fnP97DI3dlte03S7avPo_POgEV7ca4fwWZwXsBjzzdNNKNGUxwUiqNCQBlwOitUl8Soy7C2RCzBG4OyOacl_jWrwi4lZSwKnLeEOJ3zYIUVbKHtZLS_SrSEOw2erWRLnvr9av7rfgE)

---

For fun, a version using more itertools instead of the list comprehension:

```py
from itertools import islice, chain, repeat, count

x = [23, 25, 3, 45, 67, 89, 67, 45, 4, 6]

it = iter(x)
y = list(map(list, map(
        chain,
        zip(it),
        map(islice, repeat(it), count())
    )))

print(y)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU9BDoIwELz3FXtsk3pBVDz4EuOBkBI2AdqUJaF-xQsX_ZMX3-KWgu5lZnYn7czj5QI1tp_n50j1rnh_am87QDKerG0HwM5ZT4BDi5XRUDUl9hq8caYklnbsSYgJLnDN9hqygwaGnOF40lCcE0adM70JgcTe-LyclAjMWxxIdqWTkWiITMA66befvKOTSOq_iOYtWYq03FMsqdRiVIzCeeRNUKnlWnYr_QU)